# Reading a simple xml using php

Tags: php, xml

```
<key><name>testing name</name><result>success</result></key>
```

My PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'key.xml' );
$result = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "result" );
echo $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I just need to extract the text value of "result", but it doesn't output that to me. Could you help me please?

Comment: works fine for me. Make sure the file is actually loadable by `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But i am loading the xml file from a result of php output. 
$url = "http://site.com/?action=getkey";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$doc->load( $data );

Comment: the output xml is the same as that i written above.

Answer (score 4):

As per your comment, this cannot work:

```
$url = "http://site.com/?action=getkey"; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$doc->load( $data );
```

You are fetching the content from the remote URI and feed it to the function to load a file.
`DOMDocument::load` loads from a file, while `DOMDocument::loadXML()` loads from a string.

Either do

```
$doc->load( 'http://site.com/?action=getkey' );
```

or

```
$doc->loadXml( file_get_contents('http://site.com/?action=getkey') );
```

---

***On a sidenote:***

You seem to have [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) disabled. If you try to load an XML string with `DOMDocument::load` you should have received a PHP Warning. Also trying to do `$result->item(0)` should have resulted in a PHP Notice. You should always set `error_reporting(-1)` on your development machine to receive all errors, notices and warnings. Also make sure your PHP.ini has [display_errors and display_startup_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) set to true. You only want those disabled on production machines.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using a regular variable as an object here.  instead of

echo $result->item(0)->nodeValue;

why not use

echo $doc->item(0)->nodeValue;

since $doc is the instantiated object?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [DOM API](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` object, which - in contrast to `DOMDocument` - does have an `item()` method. Your answer is completely wrong.